# Creating a set of instances using a loop

Tags: java

I am trying to create a deck of cards thus create 52 instances of a class which allows me to specify the card number and suit. For example, Card(2, "Clubs") would instantiate a card with the value 2 and the suit Clubs.

I am using the following code to loop the process and store in an array instead of typing it out 52 times. It works but trying to see if I could do it better. It looks rather bad with so many if/else coding. Tried to store the suits in an enum but I am unable to call it. It doesn't seem to match a String.

Also, this method means I would end up with even more if/else when I come to the picture cards Jack, Queen, King, Ace. Please advice if there is a better approach. Thanks.

```
Card[] cards = new Card[52];  

int i = 0; 
for(int x=0; x < 4; x++){
      for(int y=2; y < 15; y++){
          if(x == 0){
              cards[i] = new Card(y, "CLUBS");  
          }
          else if(x == 1){
              cards[i] = new Card(y, "DIAMONDS"); 
          }
          else if(x == 2){
              cards[i] = new Card(y, "HEARTS"); 
          }
          else{
              cards[i] = new Card(y, "SPADES"); 
          }
          i++; 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `List` for the suits:

```
List<String> suits = new ArrayList<String>();
suits.add("CLUBS");
suits.add("DIAMONDS");
suits.add("HEARTS");
suits.add("SPADES");

Card[] cards = new Card[52];
int i = 0;
for (String suit : suits) {
    for (int y = 2; y < 15; y++) {
        cards[i] = new Card(y, suit);
        i++;
    }
}
```

You could also consider defining the suits in an enum:

```
public enum Suit {
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;
}
```

In this case your loop would change to:

```
for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
    for (int y = 2; y < 15; y++) {
        cards[i] = new Card(y, suit.name());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `java.util.Map<Integer, String>` which maps type indices to type Strings.

```
final Map<Integer, String> types = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
types.put(0, "CLUBS");
types.put(1, "DIAMONDS");
// ...

int i = 0; 
for(int x=0; x < 4; x++){
    for(int y=2; y < 15; y++){
        cards[i] = new Card(y, types.get(x));  
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always set the suit with something like this then,

```
for(int x=0; x < 4; x++) {
  // Perhaps getSuit(x)?
  String suit = "CLUBS";
  if (x == 1) suit = "DIAMONDS";
  else if (x == 2) suit = "HEARTS";
  else if (x == 3) suit = "SPADES";
  //--------------------

  for(int y=2; y < 15; y++) {
    cards[i] = new Card(y, suit);
    i++;
  }
}
```

You might also move the suit to an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to use more than one loop you could do the following

```
Card[] cards = new Card[52];
String type = "";
for(int i=0; i<52; i++) {
     if (i<13) type = "CLUBS";
     else if (i<26) type = "DIAMONDS";
     else if (i<39) type = "HEARTS";
     else type = "SPADES";
     cards[i] = new Card(i%13, type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slow way :)

```
    for (String cardType:  "CLUBS DIAMONDS HEARTS SPADES".split(" ")) {
           for (int i = 2; i < 15; i++) {
            cards[i] = new Card(i, cardType); 
        }
    }
```